# website working over http, https goes to IIS7 splash page

Tags: iis, https

Just before I get started, I just want to point out I inherited this mess from a former employee, so this isn't my design by another's, lol.

I have a domain, www.eurowelcome.co.uk. Currently I have it pointing to http, as if you were to go to http://www.eurowelcome.co.uk, it's fine, but over https (if you just add the s, you'll see) it goes to the iis splashscreen.

The bindings are as follows:

HTTP - www.eurowelcome.co.uk - 80 (port) - 172.XXX.XXX.XXX (IP)
HTTPS - www.eurowelcome.co.uk - 443 (port) - 172.XXX.XXX.XXX (IP)

The HTTPS is pointing to a wildcard SSL cert which is fine. The friendly name is fine.

I noticed the intermediate cert was gone, so I imported it, but I feel that's not really the issue. The guy did a real hatchet job here, so I'm struggling to see what the issue could be where HTTPS is getting the splash screen, and not the index page.

HTTPS is working fine on the internal network, and all the firewall settings are fine (there is another website on this IIS server that works fine with HTTPS, for example), and the default docs are in order.

I am at a loss. I can't direct all traffic to HTTPS unless the HTTPS actually shows the website.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to run two reports at least to reveal enough information, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html and https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html You also need your network administrators to help, as they can confirm whether the HTTPS traffic lands on your IIS server, not another box.

Comment: It does. 
I just noticed there's two sites running over 443, so I think the issue here is the defaultsite is taking the 443 and thus the second website will not be able to run over 443?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Just noticed that you are using IIS 7. So yes, you can only run a single HTTPS site (which is currently the default site instead of this eurowelcome site. If you can grab another IP address, then you can run two.

Comment: I created another local IP on the IIS server to bind to, would that suffice providing I update the WWW and host records in DNS?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Like this section says, you need to verify the IP based mappings to confirm that you do have two distinguished items, and then you can bind different HTTPS sites to them. DNS changes are of course necessary.

Comment: Thanks.Found the issue in the end. It was the external IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only run 1 website per IP address on HTTPS, unless SNI is enabled. So you would need another local ip address to which the website is bound.